# Asynchronous Communication

Tags: c#

I see a tutorial in how to make a [Asynchronous Communication in C#](http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/building-a-simple-chat-application-using-asynchronous-communication-and-udp-in-c/)

But I can only chat in one on one, I want to know how to chat with multiple PC,
Could I archive this without using a server? I don't know what to do, because I'm new in C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly, you could. But try to chat *using* your server. Or implement XMPP client.

Comment: I'm using WinForm Application

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted my answer, so I just deleted it. To @liran63 I'm well aware that every PC can be a server. So what I meant was... You can't have more than 2 PC chatting without a common server. If you do have any idea about this, please do share. But I've already done this, Winforms, WPF, and Web with Internet connection, and in my experience, I've never done anything like this without a common server. I could be wrong. But the OP specifically said 'chat with multiple PC'. And by 'one on one', I'm pretty sure he meant just 2 computers chatting. Did I say it right OP?

Comment: @chris_techno25 you can operate without a common server, using a ring or web-like setup. However it's easier to have the client initiating the chat be the server, as you probably suggested.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Thank you Sir. Upvoted your comment :) Yeah you're absolutely right about that. But I don't think anybody would suggest using a ring topology most especially when it comes to chat. That would cause a lot of delay in communication. It's the reason why I suggested the most common answer :)

Comment: @MarckxMan WinForm is good with everything :) Did you try to read data from remote server (static HTML, json or whatever)?

Comment: Please, show some links on how to solve my problem. I'm creating C# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are little mistaken by word "server". It is not web server, it is ordinal computer  (or even application) which serves request.
So for you multiuser chat you need to create 2 kind of application - server and client. Server will listen to clients and reply them. Usually, there is only one server and lot of clients.
I suggest you to start writing simple server/client program and then improve them.
Create server which will serve only 1 user at time. It will listen to specific port on local IP. I use **Task** to simplify program.

```
        byte[] ba = new byte[1024];
        new Task(() => {
            Output("Going to listen to messages...");
            Socket listeningS = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            // Listening to local address. You should listen to external IP for real server
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            listeningS.Bind((EndPoint)ep);
            // One and only client at a time :)
            listeningS.Listen(1);
            while (isRunning)
            {
                // Accept client, receive data and send it back
                Socket clientS = listeningS.Accept();
                int total = clientS.Receive(ba, 0, ba.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                total = clientS.Send(ba, 0, total, SocketFlags.None);
                // Client will open new connection (but later it is possible to use same)
                clientS.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                clientS.Close();

            }
        }).Start();
```

Then start with client application - it is the most easiest part - just connect, send and receive data.

```
    byte[] ba = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    s.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
    total = s.Send(ba, SocketFlags.None);
    total = s.Receive(ba, 0, ba.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    if (total > 0)
    {
        Output(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ba, 0, total));
    }
```

Next thing you should to do is to implement threads/async for your server :)

Comment: I hope you'll get the point and will move forward :)